# Assign unknown values to 2 classes

Tags: statistics

I have an array of values and I want to assign them each to two classes. 
I just know there are $2$ classes and I know the numbers are $6$, but I don't know the numbers beforehand. 
So if I have: $10, 50, 60, 11, 55, 13$, the result should be: 
group1: $10, 11, 13$
group2: $50, 55, 60$

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As you did not specify the objective function, it is hard to justify which grouping is better.

One interpretation of your task is that this could be a clustering problem.

A famous algorithm would be the [$k$-means algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) where we aim to minimize the within cluster sum of squares.

Comment: Is k-means also for 1D?

Comment: yup, it is applicable.